# How does one get all the artifacts as a zip using TeamCity Rest API?

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-7.0

[The Docs](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Patterns+For+Accessing+Build+Artifacts) show this

```
/repository/downloadAll/BUILD_TYPE_ID/BUILD_SPECIFICATION
```

for getting all of your artifacts as a zip file, but that isn't using the REST API.  Is there a way in the REST API do do the same thing?   The Docs seem to indicate that the repository links are only there for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this URL, it works for me:

```
http://<TeamcityUrl>/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/id:<BuildId>/artifacts/archived
```

I use TeamCity 9.

Comment: Thank you, because download all button in UI doesn't work correctly (downloads 1 folder), while your link works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TW/REST+API+Plugin#RESTAPIPlugin-buildartifacts

```
Artifacts:
GET <TeamcityUrl>/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/<buildLocator>/artifacts/files/<artifact relative name>
```

> If you download the artifacts from within a TeamCity build, consider using teamcity.auth.userId/teamcity.auth.password system properties as credentials for the download artifacts request: this way TeamCity will have a way to record that one build used artifacts of another and will display that on build's Dependencies tab.

have you tried this?

Comment: yes.  this gets individual build items 1 by 1.  I can use the old "downloadAll" link in my question to get a single ZIP of the entire set of artifcats.   I was looking for the REST API to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's documented, but it works.

```
http://teamcity-url/downloadArtifacts.html?buildId=216886
```

If you are using it from .NET you may use the following code:

```
List<string> downloadedFiles = new RemoteTc()
     .Connect(a => a.ToHost("tc").AsGuest())
     .DownloadArtifacts(123, @"C:\DownloadedArtifacts");
```

The above code uses [FluentTc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/fluenttc) library